# Why does setGravity() have no effect in custom ViewGroup?

Tags: android

I found this question have been asked in [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4145964/textview-gravity). But Overriding `onMeasure` method in `TextView` seems not a perfect solution. Is there any other way to get it work?